# set date format in drools workbench 7.4.1

Tags: java, drools, tomcat8

How can I set dateformat as dd-mm-yyyy in drools workbench 7.4.1?

I am using tomcat8. I tried to set it using system property -Ddrools.dateformat = dd-mm-yyyy in setenv.sh file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

There was a bug and it has been fixed in Jira - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AF-1408